# Configuring Kinco HMI as Modbus bridge

Tags: modbus, plc

In our project we use custom PLC with a single Modbus port for interaction with Kinco HMI (making the second one is possible, but very undesirable). Some HMIs made by Kinco have two Modbus ports. So that made me think that such HMI can work as a Modbus bridge. Is it possible to configure it so that on the first Modbus port Kinco works in the usual mode (master), but on the second port it works as a slave that redirects all requests to the fist Modbus port where mentioned before custom PLC is listening?